# How to remove a character from string using native mips

Tags: mips

This is a follow up of my previous question which I edited:
[How to remove a comma from string input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805225/how-to-remove-a-comma-from-string-input)

I managed to fix the infinite loop, and found a way to increment through the string. My code now can, iterate through a string(eg. 123,456) find the address of the "," and stores in $t4.

But what I can't figure out is how to shift all the numbers towards the left to remove the "," from the string(should look like this in the memory 123,456 -> 123456)

I'm using native MIPS instructions. If you could help me out like that, I would really appreciate it.

```
.globl main
.globl main2
.globl main3
.globl firstNumCountChr
.globl firstNumIncrem
.globl secondNumCountChr
.globl secondNumIncrem
.globl thirdNumCountChr
.globl thirdNumInCrem

.data  
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter first number:"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter second number:"
prompt3: .asciiz "Enter third number:"

.text              
# 0x10000000 will store first number        
# 0x10000008 will store second number      
# 0x10000010 will store third number

main:  

#display prompt1
addi $v0, $0, 4
lui $a0, 0x1000
syscall

#Input first number                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
lui $a0, 0x1000                                                                                                                                                                
ori $a0, 0x0000             #reads number into memory(0x10000000)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
addi $a1, $0, 8             #7 characters 
addi $v0, $0, 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
syscall   

#removing comma of first number
add $t1, $0, $0               #$t1 is the counter set to 0  
add $t3, $0, 0x2c             # 0x2c is acsii of "," in hex

firstNumCountChr:

lb $t2, 0($a0)            #load first byte from address in $a0
beq $t2, $0, firstNumRemoveComma     #if $t2 == 0 go to firstNumRemoveComma
or $0, $0, $0             #NOP
bne $t2, $t3, firstNumIncrem     #branch if symbol doesn't equal ","
or $0, $0, $0
add $t4, $a0, $0          #$t4 will save position of "," 

firstNumIncrem:

addi $a0, $a0, 1           #increment address
addi $t1, $t1, 1          #increment counter
j firstNumCountChr              #loop

firstNumRemoveComma:

beq $t4, $0, main2        #branch if $t4 == 0 (no comma) to main2
or $0, $0, $0             #NOP


main2:

#display prompt2
addi $v0, $0, 4
lui $a0, 0x1000
addi $a0, $a0, 20
syscall

#inputing second number                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
lui $a0, 0x1000                                                                                                                                                          
ori $a0, 0x0008             #reads number into memory(0x10000008)                                                                                           
addi $a1,$0, 8              #7 characters   
addi $v0, $0, 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
syscall 

#removing comma of second number
addi $t1, 0               # $t1 is the counter set to 0  
add $t3, 0x2c             # 0x2c is acsii of "," in hex

secondNumCountChr:

lb $t2, 0($a0)            # load first byte from address in $a0
beq $t2, $0, end          # if $t2 == 0 go to end
or $0, $0, $0             # NOP
bne $t2, $t3, secondNumIncrem     # branch if symbol doesn't equal ","
or $0, $0, $0             # NOP
add $t4, $a0, $0          # $t4 will save position of ","

secondNumIncrem:

addi $a0, $a0, 1           #increment address
addi $t1, $t1, 1          #increment counter
j secondNumCountChr               #loop    

main3:  

#display prompt3
addi $v0, $0, 4
lui $a0, 0x1000
addi $a0, $a0, 41
syscall                                                                                                                                                                

#inputting third number                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
lui $a0, 0x1000                                                                                                                                                        
ori $a0, 0x0010              #reads number into memory(0x10000010)                                                                  
addi $a1, $0, 8              #7 characters  
addi $v0,$0, 8                                                                                                                                                                                                      
syscall  

#removing comma of third number
addi $t1, 0               #$t1 is the counter set to 0  
add $t3, 0x2c             # 0x2c is acsii of "," in hex

thirdNumCountChr:

lb $t2, 0($a0)            #load first byte from address in $a0
beq $t2, $0, end          # if $t2 == 0 go to end
or $0, $0, $0
bne $t2, $t3, thirdNumInCrem     # branch if symbol doesn't equal ","
or $0, $0, $0
add $t4, $a0, $0          # $t4 will save position of ","

thirdNumInCrem: 

addi $a0, $a0, 1           #increment address
addi $t1, $t1, 1          #increment counter
j thirdNumCountChr               #loop

end:
add $0, $0, $0
```

Comment: I'd suggest to also include MIPS in the title. The tags are good to filter questions but it would help if the question itself is self contained (which it is) and the title is a self contained summary of it (which it almost is).

Comment: _"I can't figure out how to shift all the numbers towards the left to remove the ','"_ Write a loop that copies all characters efter the comma from offset X+1 to offset X.

Comment: Duplicate of [Removing Spaces from String in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527125/removing-spaces-from-string-in-mips).  Remove `','` instead of `' '`